# How can I load image url with special characters ''^" using Picasso in Android?

Tags: android

I am having an image url that has ^  symbol in it, this works properly on browser but unable to load url using Picasso. Below is the url.

http://client.codesture.com/ola/images/1521636894^1521636985218.jpg

Comment: show your full url

Comment: @HiteshSarsava please check the question I have added the url.

Comment: replace ^ to `%5E` before load image in picasso.

Answer (score 0):

Not Sure but According to [document](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/Uri#encode(java.lang.String)) Uri do not contain ^ character:

**Uri.encode(url);**

Uri specifying certain allowed characters the following works:

private static final String **ALLOWED_URI_CHARS = "@#&=*+-_.,:!?()/~'%";**

`String urlEncoded = Uri.encode(path, ALLOWED_URI_CHARS)`;

Comment: @RituRajan I want to say ^ is not allowed in URL.

Answer (score 0):

```
String imagePath = "http://client.codesture.com/ola/images/1521636894^1521636985218.jpg";
        if (imagePath.contains("^")){
            imagePath = imagePath.replace("^","%5E");
        }
```

try this solution, it will help you